# What is the relation of Aditi and Daksha?

Tags: scripture, daksha

Recently I ended up with a Facebook post from [Molee Art](https://www.facebook.com/204262919601456/posts/2500071623353896?sfns=mo)

> Daksha is Aditi's father, and Aditi is Daksha's mother, yet both are a married couple in the Vedas. Explain why and how.

But this part confused me because as per my knowledge she was the wife of Kashyap and mother of Indra, Surya etc. But I don't know her relation with Daksha, I checked [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aditi), which say:

> She is mentioned nearly 80 times in the Rigveda: the verse "Daksha sprang from Aditi and Aditi from Daksha".

So what is the exact relation between Aditi and Daksha and is it changing? Need scripture answer only.

Comment: Aditi is mother of Daksha 1 lady and another lady Aditi is daughter of Daksha.. if you have 2 ladies confusion is resolved.. :-)

Comment: @PrasannaR any scripture basis for this. If yes then feel free to answer

Comment: its pure logic..so im not answering..

Comment: @PrasannaR sound more like speculation

Comment: its normal to name daughter on grandparents name in Bharat culture.. so I will tell you one thing madhvacharya states that every name like Indra, Siva, Rudra, Brahma all are his name only he only named his created beign after his name.. now Veda can only be resolved to mean only one God that is supreme Narayana himself.. He named the creature according to his name so he is father, He brought out this brahmanda(universe)  in his stomach so he is also the mother this based some Upanishad which don't know the name..

Comment: By the way anything and everything can be denied as mere speculation its based on the belief system and preconceived notion

Comment: Aditi in Vedas is interpreted as Devi (Parvati or Adi Shakti). "Daksha sprang from Aditi and Aditi from Daksha" Daksha means ability or strength. It is because of Devi (AdiShakti ). Puranas explain it in more detail. Shiva Purana says Daksha insulted Shiva (who has this Daksha- strength, which is Shakti). Daksha (Prajapati) couldn't know that Shiva's Daksha was born as his daughter and by which he got the Daksha (ability). When he lost Sati (Daksha), Daksha lost his Daksha (strength or ability as Prajapati). Daksha also did penance for Adi Shakti and she was born as daugther (sati).

Comment: @TheDestroyer sound like a answer to me

Answer (score 3):

Rig Veda [X.72.4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10072.htm) says

> Earth sprang from the Productive Power the regions from the earth were
>   born. ***Dakṣa was born of Aditi, and Aditi was Dakṣa's Child***.

---

### ***Satapata Brahmana***

6:1:1:5 says

> That same Person became Pragâpati (lord of generation). And that
>   Person which became Pragâpati is this very Agni (fire-altar), who is
>   now (to be) built.

6:1:2:26 says

> Now that father (Pragâpati) is (also) the son: inasmuch as he created
>   Agni, thereby he is Agni's father; and inasmuch as Agni restored him,
>   thereby Agni is his (Pragâpati's) father; and inasmuch as he created
>   the gods, thereby he is the father of the gods; and inasmuch as the
>   gods restored him, thereby the gods are his fathers.

6:1:2:27 says

> Twofold verily is this,--father and son, **Pragâpati and Agni, Agni and
>   Pragâpati**, Pragâpati and the gods, the gods and Pragâpati--(for)
>   whosoever knows this.

---

Either it is **Prajapati and AGNI** or **Daksha and Aditi**, the concept is SPIRITUAL but not physical.

So whatever is born from the BRAHMAN will become BRAHMAN and be merged again back into the BRAHMAN.

Answer (score 0):

Its funny how people decode the stories of vedas in human form. Vedas are all about science. Everything else in vedas apart from science is just noise.

Daksha and Aditi were not real human beings. Rather Daksha and Aditi are terms (names) referred to elementary particles (like newly discovered Higgs Boson) that are responsible for the process of creation.

It is same as how an elementary particle splits itself into two different particles due to interactions with quantum fields. This explains Aditi sprang from Daksh and Daksh from Aditi. Aditi with her 7 out of 8 children took the process of creation forward. That's the reason why aditi is referred as mother of indra, sun, etc. Hence those 7 children could be rest of the particles that are responsible for creation of this universe like photon, neutron, protons, etc.

Please stop giving human forms to gods. An energy this big cannot exist in a human body because our body cannot handle that amout. Not just krishna and rama are avtar or vishnu but every single particle, matter and antimatter everything is avtar of vishnu. Every animal, every plant, every insect and every human being just like rama and krishna.
(Kan kan me bhagwan hai, kehne ko to pata sabko hai, lekin maanta koi nhi)

Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesha were never real humans rather

Brahma is referred to the collective consciousness,

Vishnu is the space (the ultimate quantum field) that exists everywhere, even in the vaccum (something in nothing) that is constantly wobbling throughout the universe giving birth to particles. This field is the main source of energy.

And Mahesha or Shiva is the Time.

Vishnu and Shiva together are the Space-Time.

And all three together forms the state of nothingness, the quantum state.

Comment: Sir this is purely ur own thought. A simple question, so u mean Ramkrishna Paramhamsa, Bamakhepa, 4 Vaishnavacharyas were hallucinating while describing the forms of deities? U mean Meera sang the songs of love for photons & neutrons? U mean Adishankaracharya while describing devi in Soundaryalahari, was describing nuclear energy? Indeed at subtuler level the terms have a deep meaning & wht u said is partially corect. But, not that they didn't had a body. & firstly Vishnu & Shiv have no human body. Incase you want to prove your point valid kindly cite source from some prominent Acharya's wrok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).