# What's the oldest advaita ashram or mathas?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, ashram

The title is the question. But I know Shankara mathas are the oldest, I'm not considering them for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The term [Advaita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta) refers to its idea that the true self, Atman, is the same as the highest metaphysical Reality (Brahman).

Earliest reference to Advaita can be traced to [Rig Veda Hymn  X.72 and in Satapada Brahmana 6:1:1:5](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37650/3869).

While in Rig Veda it was mentioned as **Aditi and Daksha** and in Satapada Brahmana it is was mentioned as **Prajapati and AGNI**.

---

Coming to the question part, we have to remember that [Sri Gaudapada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta#Gaudapada_and_M%C4%81%E1%B9%87%E1%B8%8Dukya_K%C4%81rik%C4%81), Sri Sankara's grand Guru, and [Adi Sankara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta#Adi_Shankara) was known proponents of Advaita in the recent past.

[Sri Gaudapada Mutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shri_Gaudapadacharya_Math), also known as Kavaḷē maṭha (कवळे मठ), located in Kavale, Ponda, Goa, is the oldest matha of the Smarthan Saraswat Brahmins.

However, there is a controversy as to the [birth-dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara#Birth-dates) of Sri Sankara.  The earliest period attributed was around 500 BCE.

[All the Mutts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shankaracharya#Establishment_of_the_Tradition) established by Sri Sankara during his life time.  If we go by this theory, then the Mutts Sri Sankara should be the oldest Advaita Mutts.